# Bulk loading files into MarkLogic using MLCP fails

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am trying to use MLCP to bulk load files into MarkLogic.  Command line and error are below.  I followed the instructions in one of the tutorials.  I dont know why its doing anything with hadoop if my mode is local.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

> T:\temp\gs>mlcp.bat import -mode local -host localhost -port 8000
>   -username admin -password admin -input_file_path T:\temp\gs\import -input_file_type documents -document_type xml

The error is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: failure to login: No
>   LoginModules configured for hadoop_simple

Comment: Can you update the question to include the versions of MLCP and ML?

Comment: I believe mlcp still uses some hadoop libraries for local mode, though I don't know the details of how that works (though source code is at https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump ). A search for "No LoginModules configured for hadoop_simple" shows other instances of this, and it seems related to JAAS configuration. Perhaps there's something in your JVM configuration related to JAAS that's creating issues here? Just grasping, I've never seen this error with mlcp before. Try ingesting just a single document, and don't include the "-mode" argument, as it defaults to local.

Comment: I'm using version 8.0.6 of mlcp.  I tried without the mode and just one file.  no luck.

Comment: Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured
for hadoop_simple at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:264)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:381)         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.newLoginContext(UserGroupInformation.java:462)         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:723)

Comment: Looks like it works!  if you post as an answer I can verify it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may have downloaded the MapR version - I just tried a minimal import with the MapR version and got the same error. Make sure you get the non-MapR version (I'm assuming you don't need MapR here) - it's the first Download link at developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp